# How to programmatically determine the prior time period based upon unix time stamps in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, unix

Essentially I have two unix timestamps, representing the first and last days of a given month. Is it possible programmatically determine the timestamps for the first and last of the previous month?

For example, I have the following two timestamps:
`1467331201` --> `July 1, 2016`
`1469923201` --> `July 31, 2016`

Essentially, can I manipulate these two numbers in a consistent way in order to the unix time (or Date object) for June 1, 2016 and June 30, 2016, respectively? Problem that I'm running into is that you cannot simply subtract a given amount because the amount of days in a month is variable.

Comment: Why one second after midnight?

Comment: Are you asking how you can get the unix timestamp for the first and last day of a given month? (without knowing the number of days in the month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this function:

```js
function getPreviousMonthRange(unixTime) {
    var dt = new Date(unixTime * 1000);
    dt.setUTCDate(0); // flips to the last day of previous month
    var unixLast = dt.getTime();
    dt.setUTCDate(1); // back to the first day of that same month
    var unixFirst = dt.getTime();
    return [unixFirst / 1000, unixLast / 1000];
}

// given first and last date (only one is really needed)
var unixTimeFirst = 1467331201;
var unixTimeLast = 1469923201;

// get previous month's first & last date
var [first, last] = getPreviousMonthRange(unixTimeFirst);

// output
console.log('previous month first day: ', first, new Date(first*1000));
console.log('previous month last day: ', last, new Date(last*1000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following example:

```js
// Specify a timestamp
var timestamp = 1467331201;

// Create a date object for the time stamp, the object works with milliseconds so multiply by 1000
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

// Set the date to the previous month, on the first day
date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth() - 1, 1);

// Explicitly set the time to 00:00:00
date.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0);

// Get the timestamp for the first day
var beginTimestamp = date.getTime() / 1000;

// Increase the month by one, and set the date to the last day of the previous month
date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth() + 1, 0);

// Explicitly set the time to 23:59:59
date.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59);

// Get the timestamp for the last day
var endTimestamp = date.getTime() / 1000;

// Print the results
console.log('Timestamps for previous month: ');
console.log('Begin timestamp: ' + beginTimestamp);
console.log('End timestamp: ' + endTimestamp);
```

A timestamp must be specified in the variable on the top, this might be one of the two timestamps you suggested in your question, anywhere in a month.

This code then calculates the begin and end timestamp for the previous month as you've requested, and prints the results to the console.

Please note, that in this example the begin timestamp uses `00:00:00` as time, and the end timestamp uses `23:59:59` as time (the last second of that day). This can be configured the way you'd prefer.

In this case, we're working with the `...UTC...` `Date` functions, because a Unix timestamp is in UTC time, not in the timezone the user is in.

The statement `date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1, 0);` is used to select the last day in the month. The next month is selected first, but because the day is set to `0` (and not `1`) one day is subtracted giving you the preferred result. This is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Description).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Moment.js. I'm sure this is not exactly how you'd end up handling it but see below for an example of some helpful methods.

```
var lastDayOfJuly = moment(1469923201);
var firstDayOfJuly = lastDayOfJuly.startOf('month');
var lastDayOfJune = firstDayOfJuly.subtract(1, 'day');
var firstDayOfJune = lastDayOfJune.startOf('month");
```

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)